# Converting a CGRect of a object in a subview in UITableViewCell in UITable to CGRect with respect to self.view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, interface-builder

I want to convert a `CGRect` "aRect" of a object in a subview in `UITableViewCell` in `UITableView` to `CGRect` with respect to `self.view`.

The problem is that aRect is with respect to the subview in the table cell.
But i want to make it so that it is with respect to `self.view`.

What i tried is this

```
rect = [self.view convertRect:aRect.frame toView:cellView];
```

but it doesn't work.

So how to convert it?

Comment: Is there a typo with "aRect.frame" ? It should be "aRect" instead.

Comment: OH yea, it's a typo.  but when i removed .frame, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since `convertRect:toView:` actually deals with a `CGRect` *in the receiver’s coordinate system,* maybe `[cellView convertRect:theFrame toView:self.view]` (i.e. swapping the two views in your call) will work as you intended.

Comment: thx evadne.
By the way drawnonward, what is the difference between toView variant and fromView variant?

Comment: Calling the `toView` variant means that the rect is in the view’s coordinate system and we want to know its equivalent in the other view’s coordinate system.  Calling the `fromView` variant means that we want to know where a rect residing in the other view will be placed in the receiver view.