# How do I get the position of subview in my UITableViewCell with respect to the whole window?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

I know `convertRect:toRect` is the key here, but I'm not sure how to call it. I have a subview of my cell, and I want its position in the app's entire window.

I need to know this when I tap on this button (the subview) in its target action method. I need to call the `convertRect:toRect` function on the cell, I figure, in order to get the right coordinates, but in this method I have no reference to the cell itself.

Do I climb the superview hierarchy? That seems gross, as I'm not totally sure what I would get, as it's embedded in the contentView of the cell, and Apple does wacky stuff with their private subviews and whatnot.

Code:

```
@IBAction buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    // This button got the callback that it was pressed. It's in a cell. I need to convert its rect to that of the window here. I need the coordinate system it's calculated from (the cell) which I'm not sure of how to easily do in a target action callback.
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - Get Position of UIView within entire UIWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465394/iphone-get-position-of-uiview-within-entire-uiwindow)

Comment: @LyndseyScott No, this is a specific case in the context of cell subviews, where it's not straightforward to get the reference view of the view.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: @LyndseyScott Because it's the very issue I'm struggling with? If in the above situation it's trivial to get reference to the cell the subview is contained in, share your solution.

Comment: I agree with rmaddy's solution. You don't need a reference to the cell... just the button. You don't need to convert the button to the cell's coordinate system then convert that to the window's. It can be done in one step.

Comment: If you want the coordinates of the button relative to the main window then it is as simple as the code in my answer.

Comment: @LyndseyScott When I pass the button, the resulting rect is incorrect. It's only correct when I climb the superview tree until I find the cell.

Comment: @rmaddy I tried the code in your solution. It simply doesn't work.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". You've posted enough question here to know that those are meaningless words.

Comment: I thought you'd read the reply above. "When I pass the button, the resulting rect is incorrect."

Comment: How incorrect is it? Try passing `self.frame` instead of `self.bound`. Does that fix it?

Comment: No. From [this question and the corresponding answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3034886/998117) I can't help but think I need the cell itself.

Comment: Do this - take a screenshot with your button in place. Log the button's frame and the converted frame. Measure the actual position of the button in the screenshot (in points, not pixels). Update your question with all of this info.

Comment: The delta? It's off about 50pts on the y axis, seemingly the vertical distance of the button from the top of the cell.

Comment: @DougSmith There was a typo in my answer. rdelmar noticed it. See the update. It should fix the delta you were seeing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's actually very simple:

```
CGRect windowRect = [someSubview convertRect:someSubview.bounds toView:nil];
```

Assuming you have a button handler:

```
- (void)someButtonHandler:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = sender;

    // do your stuff

    CGRect windowRect = [button convertRect:button.bounds toView:nil];
}
```

Of course it's even easier if your method is setup as:

```
- (void)someButtonHandler:(UIButton *)button {
}
```

Comment: How do I get `someSubview` in this case outlined in the question?

Comment: That's up to you. Your question makes it sound like you already have the subview. If not, clarify your question because it is unclear what you have.

Comment: I do have the subview and I thought the question made that clear. The subview is in a cell. Calling the `convertRect` code on the subview doesn't present the correct result, as its coordinate system is in terms of the cell it's contained in.

Comment: Update your question with the actual code where you want to convert the subview's frame.

Comment: Done. I don't think it's much different than the situation I've outlined, but I hope it helps.

Comment: What is "self" in your code? Shouldn't that be button?

Comment: You still have one more "self" in the first line. Anyway, thanks for clearing up a misconception that I've apparently had all a long, that the receiver had to be the superview of the view whose rect you were converting. This might be the misunderstanding @DougSmith has with this answer too, since he thinks he needs to get a reference to the cell.

Comment: @rdelmar Fixed the other `self`. Thanks. Note that `[button convertRect:button.bounds toView:someOtherView]` is the same as `[button.superview convertRect:button.frame toView:someOtherView]`.

Comment: Yeah, I was just testing that to make sure I understood what I had been doing, and why it gave me the same result as the way you're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Solution**
converting `myView`'s frame to the corresponding frame in the `parentView`

```swift
let myViewGlobalFrame = myView.convert(myView.frame, to: parentView)
```