# How to get the position of a uibutton (subview of UITableViewCell) with respect to the whole window iOS objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, coordinates

As the question says,I want to get the position of a uibutton as shown in the image and I have to show a pop up menu from that uibutton(in the tableviews view).

I went through [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27596565/how-do-i-get-the-position-of-subview-in-my-uitableviewcell-with-respect-to-the-w) and [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572304/get-position-of-uiview-in-respect-to-its-superviews-superview).But these are giving me different locations.

I use the code

```
    CGRect windowRect = [_tableView convertRect:button.frame fromView:tempCell];
```

temp cell is my selected cell.

I am using kxMenu for popUp menu,and I use the following code.

```
[KxMenu showMenuInView:_tableView
              fromRect:windowRect
             menuItems:menuItems];
```

So,I need to get the windowRect correctly.Anybody have any idea?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What did you use the method in Question 1 you linked? It looks like it should help you when used like this : `CGRect windowRect = [button convertRect:button.bounds toView:nil];`

Comment: i use this code to get and seems correct `CGPoint windowPoint = [button convertPoint:button.bounds.origin toView:self.view];` (using this in scrollview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
 [_tableView convertRect:button.frame fromView:tempCell];
```

It will convert frame of the button wrt tempcell to button frame wrt _tableView

If you want to get the frame of button wrt the window, you should do either

```
 [button convertRect:button.bounds toView:nil];
```

or

```
 [button.superView convertRect:button.frame toView:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `nestedView.frame` will give you the origin points respective to the immediate parent. Here is the Swift 5 version of this answer:

```
let frame: CGRect? = nestedView.superview?.convert(nestedView.frame, to: nil)
```

Objective-C version is as follows:

```
 CGRect frame = [nestedView.superView convertRect:nestedView.frame toView:nil];
```

This will give you the frame of the nestedView relative to the superview's superview. Hope this helps.

Comment: looks like the correct solution, but the OP did ask for Obj-C. Should be trivial for them to them convert however